# JS Svg Pan Zoom doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg

I'm trying to use this [library](https://github.com/timmywil/jquery.panzoom) to implement a SVG pan zoom.

This is my code:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
    <svg>...</svg>
</div>
<div class="controls">
    <button id="zoom-in">+</button>
    <button id="zoom-out">-</button>
    <button id="reset">r</button>
    <button id="activate"  onclick="clickf()">activate</button>
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function clickf() {
    var $section = $('svg');
    var $pz = $section.panzoom();
    document.getElementById('zoom-in').addEventListener('click', function (ev) {
        ev.preventDefault()
        $pz.panzoom("zoom");

    });
    document.getElementById('zoom-out').addEventListener('click', function (ev) {
        ev.preventDefault()
        $pz.panzoom("zoom", true);
    });
    document.getElementById('reset').addEventListener('click', function (ev) {
        ev.preventDefault()
        $pz.panzoom("reset");
    });  
}
```

It seems that the Zoom works fine but the Pan doesn't. I don't understand why. Someone has some suggestions?

Comment: your javascript doesn't seem to implement pan, only zoom.

Comment: No, it should work with ar $pz =$section.panzoom();...https://jsfiddle.net/grx4mbyg/

Comment: It works only with JQuery 3.1